# proteus error: Invalid opcode 0x000D at PC=0x0118

Tags: microcontroller, avr, codevisionavr

I wrote this code on `Bascom` but as I run and click on keypad on `Proteus` I see this error:

```
Invalid opcode 0x000D at PC=0x0118
```

this is my code on `Bascom`

```
$regfile = "m16def.dat"
$crystal = 1000000
Config Kbd = Portd , Debounce = 30
Config Lcd = 16 * 2
Config Lcdpin = Pin , Db4 = Portb.4 , Db5 = Portb.5 , Db6 = Portb.6 , Db7 = Portb.7 , Rs = Portb.3 , E = Portb.2
Dim Adad As Byte
Dim Andis As Byte
Dim Lable As Byte

Scan1:
Waitms 200
Adad = 0
Andis = Getkbd()
If Andis > 15 Then Goto Scan1

Lable = Lookup(andis , Dta)
If Lable < 10 Then
Adad = Adad * 10
Adad = Adad + Lable
Lcd Adad
End If

Dta:
Data 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 11 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 12 , 13 , 0 , 14 , 15
```

and this is my `proteus` simulation for `simple calculation`:
[image]

and as I click on keypad I see this:
[image]

I do not have any idea what have happen there.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the version of the PIC or of its type. For example when using it with arduino you have to specify the type (UNO, NANO, MEGA).

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the .include at the first
I faced this problem while programing in assembly avr on the same program (proteus) using the atmega328p. I fortgot to put the inculde at 1st and i had a demo version of the proteus (which requires to be run as administrator every time you launch the application again). Try this and let me know it it worked.